# PHP file_put_contents Failed to open stream, invalid argument

Tags: php

Please help! I have tried figuring this out for over an hour
What i am trying to do is to get form values via POST, and then put these into a timestamped txt file
The error i get is:

> Warning: file_put_contents(D:\wamp\www\weboldal\hu\php\en\03-14-15-11:08:48.txt): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in D:\wamp\www\weboldal\hu\php\en\formprocessing2.php on line 18

```
if ($_POST["type"] == "Type1") {
    print "Type1";
    $filename = date("m-d-y-h:i:s");
    $fullfilename = "D:\\wamp\\www\\weboldal\\hu\\php\\en\\".$filename.".txt";
    print $fullfilename;
    while (file_exists($fullfilename)) {
        print "Please wait a few seconds, server is busy";
        sleep(1);
    }
    $type = $_POST["type"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $contents = $type."r\n".$name."r\n".$email."r\n".$password;
    file_put_contents($fullfilename,$contents,LOCK_EX);
```

EDIT: The problem was that windows would not accept colons in the filename, thanks to user @Hobo Sapiens for pointing that out

Comment: The error is fairly straight forward, are you absolutely sure that the filepath is correct?

Comment: I'd guess that Windows doesn't like all those colons in the filename.

Comment: @Neil Masters I tested with getchwd() and it returned "D:\wamp\www\weboldal\hu\php\en"

Comment: @RamRaider user "Hobo Sapiens" already fixed it, the problem was that Windows doesnt support ":" in filenames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows will reject the filename with the timestamp as it is because of the colons. Remove those and you should be fine.

Comment: LoLoL, I would have been troubleshooting this stupid simple mistake for centuries, nay millenia.  Wish you were a member to get points for that.